# How to populate data from SQL Server database columns to textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to populate data from a SQL Server database from many columns to many textboxes .. I have a code to populate just one box .. can someone edit my code... I want to pull data and show it in Name, Address, Telephone No and Date ... plz help .. this code works for only one textbox..

Thanks in advance

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=rex;Initial Catalog=PersonalDetails;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select * From PersonalUsers ", Conn);

Conn.Open();
SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

if (DR1.Read())
{
    Name.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that you should be using a `using` block for the command and connection objects. Additionally you shouldn't be setting text boxes here. This data access should be on its own layer that returns an object. Higher up in your application you would populate your text boxes via this object.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (DR1.Read())
{

    if(DR1.GetName() == "YourSQLColumnName")
    {
      YourTextBox.Text = (string) DR1["YourSQLColumnName"];
    }

    // Your Other textboxes and columns which you want to match should follow as this template
}
```

Comment: for a little bit performance gain order datareader column reads as your table's ordering.. i.e. if the Phone named column is the first column write it into first match order..

Cause SQLDataReader Reads 1 way.. with this small trick you won't have faults or wrong/null reads

Comment: :) if you dont have a column as the name of "YourSQLColumnName" it is very very normal ;) You should correct it with your real column names.. it's a template code-part..Means shows you the way..its not for copy-paste ;)

Comment: no mate ..i changed the code.. i put the correct column name ... and it still gives me that error ... i had changed the Sqlcommand to  (Select * from PersonalUsers) not sure if it will work with this

Comment: Please check your columnnames' spelling again.. for c-Sharp language ( "Column1", "COlumn1" "COLUMN1", "coLUmn1" ) all are different objects..

So, if your SQL Table's column name declared as the name of "cOlumn1" and if you write in this query as "column1" datareader can' t find the column ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, _conn);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
System.Data.DataTable tbl = new System.Data.DataTable("Results");
tbl.Load(rdr);

if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
   Name.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["column_name"].ToString();
```

Comment: My bad:  I've fixed the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
string cs=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
using(OracleConnection con=new OracleConnection(cs))
{
sql="select empname from Emp where empno='"+empno+"'";
OracleCommand cmd  = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand(sql,con);
con.Open();
OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(rdr.Read())
{
EmpName.Text=Convert.ToString(rd["empname"]);
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context or details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would like to take care of both more rows and more columns.

- Try to specify the columns. It works without, but the performance is better if you do so.
- I assume you have a class called PersonalUser with the specifed properties.
- It is also nice to have it in an sorted order, so I added that

```
    public List<PersonalUser> FetchMyData()
    {

        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=rex;Initial Catalog=PersonalDetails;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select Name, Address, TelephoneNo,Date From PersonalUsers order by Name", Conn);

        Conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

        var result = new List<PersonalUser>();
        while (DR1.Read())
        {
            result.Add(new PersonalUser {
                Name = DR1.GetString(0);
                Address= DR1.GetString(1);
                TelephoneNo = DR1.GetString(2);
                Date = DR1.GetString(3)
              }
           );
        }


        return result;
    }
```

I would also, if the need is getting much complex than this, conidering using Entity Framwork..